# Error al desplegar Aplicacion Nuxt3 con Docker en Servidor Amazon EC2

Tags: javascript, docker, deployment, ec2, nuxt

estoy intentando desplegar a un servidor de Amazon, usando Docker, pero me da un error y parece ser que no esta instalando bien el proyecto, ya que no hay carpeta de Node_Modules...

Llega hasta el final del DockerFile, pero falla ahí, no tengo claro si el npm install lo esta haciendo bien, pero por terminal voy viendo como lo va componiendo, y cuando llega al nuxt start me dice esto:

```
---> Running in 6312c4ea3532
Removing intermediate container 6312c4ea3532
 ---> cf362376dd9b
Step 12/12 : CMD [ "nuxt", "start"]
 ---> Running in 7e28afc1529d
Removing intermediate container 7e28afc1529d
 ---> d986ac3b032d
Successfully built d986ac3b032d
Successfully tagged front_app:latest
Recreating front_app_1 ... done
Attaching to front_app_1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
   throw err;
   ^
```

**Mi fichero Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:20.11-alpine3.18

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1200

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "nuxt", "start"]
```

**Mi fichero docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:3000
```

Y este es el error que me da:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
 throw err;
 ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/nuxt-app/nuxt'
   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.11.1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
 throw err;
 ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/nuxt-app/nuxt'
   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}
```